# System.IO.FileNotFoundException - CefSharp.Core.dll not found in release

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I've downloaded the CefSharp extension with NuGet reposity and I've tested it with Microsoft Visual Studio.
I've used the default code, it is:

```
namespace WebBrowser
{
    public partial class WebForm : Form
    {
        public WebForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }

        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public void InitBrowser()
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void WebForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If I run the project in debug, it works well: it open a window with Google.
But if I compile the project and I install it with the setup, I get always an error:
*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies.*

I've searched on Google, I've tried adding `xcopy "$(SolutionDir)packages\cef.redist.x86.3.2987.1601\CEF*" "$(TargetDir)" /s /y /i` in post compilation and other ways, but nothing works.

What can I try?

Comment: Does the "TargetDir" contain CefSharp.Core.dll library and its dependencies after build?

Comment: The setup installs the software in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\SetupWebBrowser" and it contains CefSharp.Core.dll, CefSharp.WinForms.dll, CefSharp.dll, System.Net.Http.dll and the .exe. Is it?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I found what is the cause of your problem. CefSharp needs to have some files in root application directory. 
 In setup project, when selecting files for Application folder, choose `Add => File...`  instead of `Add => Project Output...`. Then navigate to your build folder and pick all files. This will create 1 to 1 copy of your output files when running setup executable.

Comment: can you show us with pictures please. I dont understand

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and solved it by installing the following redistributable:

[image: Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable]